# Robots.txt - allow the bots to visit only via htts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, robots.txt

Our site uses https only, so anything http gets forced to use https. But there are still some bots that want to force their way into via http.

I've search but could not find a simple way to do this.

So my question is, what should i write to robots.txt so that i allow only https

Answer (score 0):

Write a hard 302 redirect to https. If there is a http only bot it's not a search engine bot. Google, Yahoo and Bing accepting https only. You can ignore all other bots.

Answer (score 0):

If you use HTTP 301 to redirect from HTTP to HTTPS, capable bots will notice the redirect (and, depending on the bot’s purpose, follow it, update their index, etc.). If you want to disallow crawling of your HTTP URLs, note that bots won’t be able to learn that the pages now have new URLs, because they are not allowed to access them to notice the redirect (in case you have or had HTTP links).

If you still want to disallow crawling of HTTP URLs, place the following robots.txt at `http://example.com/` (or `http://www.example.com/` or whatever your host is) and do **not** redirect this specific URL to `https://example.com/robots.txt`.

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```